# How to capture results of iperf continuously using exec() in java?

Tags: java, command-line, iperf

I want to capture results of IPerf3 program and send them to GUI of JAVA swing, and represent them by chartpanel.

But I encoutered as a serious problem.

There is a snippet of code I've ever used.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

// read in the output from Iperf
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
errors = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

Thread t = new Thread(){
    public synchronized void run(){
         String input_line = null;
           try{
              while (input != null && (input_line = input.readLine()) != null  && !input_line.equals(""))
            {
                    //  System.out.println("getting msg now ...");
                    parseLine(input_line);
                    frame.logMessage(input_line);
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
};
t.start();
```

And then example of command is "iperf3 -f M -i 1 -c iperf.he.net -p 5201 -P 1 -t 10".

> As you know, this iperf3 service sends data to client(or server) by
>   time interval(here, one second), so when I got one result per second,
>   I want to send to GUI ( here, parseLine() does do it) as soon as I get
>   result.

But, parseLine() inside while statement of Thread.run() get to be executed, when all of 10 results received, in other words when the iperf3 service finished running.

I have a doubt that there is a problem in using

> BufferedReader

for inputing line.

Now, I got into trouble of this issue, and I want developers who have a rich experience in java and iperf, to really help me.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You can use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to first set-up the input capturing and then start the process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [force flush](https://www.mankier.com/1/iperf3#--forceflush)  Can't speak to the rest of the code.

Bob

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for your answer. Your suggestion works fine, thanks again.